# Monotonicity and optima of functions

Tags: optimization

It is said that the logarithm is a monotonically increasing function, hence the logarithm of a function achieves its maximum value at the same points as the function itself.

Is there a similar property for monotonically decreasing functions and minimization, e.g, the minimum points for $f(x)$ and $e^{-f(x)}$ are the same?

Comment: Yes, because monotonicity preserves order.

Comment: @copper.hat increasing preserves order but decreasing reverses order..

Comment: @Surb: I understand that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $f$ be some function

- If $g$ is strictly monotonically increasing, then $g(f(x))$ has the same minimizer and maximizer as $f(x)$
- If $g$ is strictly monotonically decreasing, then the minimizers of $g(f(x))$ are the maximizer of $f(x)$ and the maximizers of $g(f(x))$ are the minimizer of $f(x)$.